# Set Input type=date

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, input

Thank you very much for your time

My question is How to set value input of type date?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
```

that it comes after Run

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date" value="">
```

I made an some code in this manner

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var date = $('#StartDate').val();
    var dt = new Date(date);
    var day = parseInt(dt.getDate());
    var month = parseInt(dt.getMonth() + 1);
    var year = parseInt(dt.getFullYear());

    if (day < 10) { day = '0' + day }
    if (month < 10) { month = '0' + month }
    var setDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    $('#StartDate').val(setDate);
});
```

When the program runs I see the value from the debugger screen is string.empty

```
var date = "";
```

also I tried to remove this one the lower portion of format error again.

```
var dt = new Date(date);
```

but I didnt work.
if anyone knows the answer to this
I really need help
Finally Coming data in view but 
value does not show because of format is different.
This required format(yyyy-MM-dd)

Thank you to everyone.

Comment: did you try using `@Html.TextBoxFor` ?? your rendered html has `value=""` empty.. so even in your script it is empty

Comment: What is it your trying to do? If you want to display a value in the textbox, then set the value of `StartDate` in the controller before you pass the model to the view. And if you want to format it, Use the `DisplayFormatAttribute` (or `TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { ... })`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you  Using these data can reach this one Html.TextBoxFor Losing the date attribute but otherwise you have given me ideas

Comment: @SelmanErhanekici, Its just `new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" }` if you want `type="date"` (I just kept the code in my comment to the minimum). The key point was that you script is pointless. You need to set the value in the controller.

Comment: I got it and you right.I solved the problem.You changed my perspective.   @StephenMuecke Thank you for taking the time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is unnecessary, and since property `StartDate` is a nullable `DateTime?` and has no value (your html has `value=""`) then `var dt = new Date(date);` will return `Invalid date` because `var date = $('#StartDate').val();` returns `null` and the script fails.

You need to set the value of `StartDate` in the controller before you pass the model to the view, for example

```
var model = new MyModel() { StartDate = DateTime.Today };
return View(model);
```

which will display today's date in the input.

In order to display the required format, you can add the `DisplayFormatAttribute`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

Note adding the `DataTypeAttribute` means you can omit the `type="date"` from your `EditorFor()` method as that will be added by the method

Alternatively you can omit both attributes and use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" }})
```